# How to copy an UIElement fast?

Tags: c#, wpf, uielement

I need to copy an `UIElement`.
I searched for a solution and found this example:

```
string saved = XamlWriter.Save(canvas1); 
StringReader sReader = new StringReader(saved); 
XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader); 
Canvas newCanvas = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(xReader); 
stackPanel2.Children.Add(newCanvas);
```

It worked perfectly.
My application copies a long list of `UIElement`s and I found that it takes a lot of time.
Does somebody have an idea how to copy `UIElement`s faster?

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method on UIElement:

```
static class ExtMethods
{
    public static T GetCopy<T>(this T element) where T : UIElement
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            XamlWriter.Save(element, ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)XamlReader.Load(ms);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
Canvas copy = canvas1.GetCopy();
```

Comment: That's not faster than the OP's approach.